# Population autocovariance goes to zero, assuming covariance stationary

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, expected-value, covariance, autoregressive

In time series context, let $\gamma_j=E[(y_t-\mu)(y_{t-j}-\mu)]$ denote population autocovariance, where $\mu$ is population mean of $y_t$, assuming covariance-stationary. Then, $\gamma_j$ goes to $0$ as $j$ goes to $\infty$.

Covariance-stationary means the autocovariance only depends on $j$, not on $t$.

I have been trying to use algebra to prove $\gamma_j$ goes to $0$ for a while, but cannot figure it out. Could anyone give me a hint on how to understand this limiting behavior?

Comment: Because the conclusion isn't always correct, you must be assuming something more than you have stated.  Counterexamples are given by time series where every $y_t$ is the same (finite nonzero variance) random variable, for which $\gamma_j$ is a nonzero constant.  Could you give us the full set of assumptions about $(y_t)$?

Comment: @whuber You could assume regression coefficients $|\phi_j|<1$ and $\sum \phi_j<\infty$.

Comment: You still haven't told us anything about the process.  Presumably it's an AR(1) process, but you haven't stipulated that--and the conclusion does not hold for general covariance-stationary processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that $y_t$ follows AR(1) process, such that 
$$y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + e_t$$
Then, it can be easily shown that the covariance between $y_t$ and $y_{t-j}$ is : 
$$cov(y_t, y_{t-j} )= \phi^{\,j}\, var(y_t)$$

Since, $|\phi| < 1 $ (condition for process to be stationary), therefore, $cov(y_t, y_{t-j} )$ approaches to zero as $j$ tends to infinity.

Similar results can be easily generalised for any ARMA model.

Comment: Actually, $\phi=1$ is possible, too.  Stationarity then implies $\operatorname{Var}(e_t)=0.$

Comment: @whuber Thanks, but if $Var(e_t)$ is zero, then $y_t$ would become a deterministic variable, not a random variable any more.

Comment: That's not the case.  For instance, let $y_0$ be a standard Normal random variable and generate $y_1 = y_0 + 0,$ $y_2 = y_1 + 0,$ *etc.*  (You can similarly generate $y_i$ for negative $i.$) That's a genuinely random process.